# ionic 3 angular native screenshot fails with typeError

Tags: angular, ionic3

i am using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screenshot/

and my code looks like:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Screenshot } from '@ionic-native/screenshot';

providers: [
    StatusBar,
    ThemeProvider,
    OpportunityService,
    Screenshot,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**home.ts**

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public screenshot: Screenshot) {
                this.showRow = false;
  }

getFeedback(){
       // this.screenshot.save('jpg', 100,'vik.jpg')
       this.screenshot.save('jpg', 80, 'myscreenshot.jpg').then(
            () => alert('got it'),
            (err) => console.log(err)
        );
   }
}
```

But i see error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
    at index.js:54
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at Screenshot.save (index.js:53)
    at
```

Comment: It looks right to me. Upvoted maybe somebody else can help.

Answer (score 0):

You imported it into app.module.ts but did you import the screenshot in your home.ts?

```
import { Screenshot } from '@ionic-native/screenshot';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Newer versions ionic 4+

```
import { Screenshot } from '@ionic-native/screenshot/ngx';
```

Note: This will work on real device not with ionic serve.